# Can i use Vaadin to make google chrome extensions/apps?

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, vaadin

I saw that I can make chrome extensions using GWT.
I am wondering if I can make the same thing with Vaadin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vaadin applications are always run on a server. That doesn't prevent you from using Vaadin in a Chrome extension, but it does mean you have to host the server-side logic somewhere. You'll also have to establish custom a communication channel between Chrome and your Vaadin app to access the chrome.* APIs, which is prone to security issues. It also means you'll have to write quite a bit of non-Vaadin code to make it work.